# rolling autocorrelation function for a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, correlation

I have a R dataframe, and I need to compute autocorrelation for every column of it for several rolling time windows.
I used the following solution

```
myacf=function(x,lag){
return(acf(x, na.action=na.pass,lag.max=lag)[lag])
}

for(i in 2:dim(dfres)[1]){
  print(i)
  col=rollapply(as.numeric(dfres[,i]),width=oneday,FUN=myacf,lag=oneday) 
}
```

where dfres is a matrix (I exclude the first column since it contains timestamps), and rollapply is from the package zoo.
I obtain the following error: error in plot.window(need finite 'ylim' values).
Anyway I don't need plots, but just the values of autocorrelation in the chosen lag. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "None of them works" . In order for us to advise on this issue, updating your post with a [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) could help.

Comment: I edited the original post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

With `lapply` you can operate the `rollapply` function on each column resulting in 
    `acf` series for the selected lag value. We then use `Reduce` to combine results from the above step.

I have used dataset `edhec` from `PerformanceAnalytics` package for this demo. You
    can change the `width` parameter accordingly.

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")

#load test dataset
data(edhec,package="PerformanceAnalytics")

#select subset with fewer columns
edhec_sub = edhec[,1:5]

fn_lag_ACF = function(lagValue = x) {


#for width as 1 year calculate acf for input lagValue for each column

acfList = lapply(edhec_sub,function(x) {


 TS = rollapply(x, width = 12,
 FUN = function(z) acf(z,na.action=na.pass,lag.max= lagValue,plot=FALSE)$acf[lagValue],
                by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
 colnames(TS) = colnames(x)             

 return(TS) 

})

#combine acf output for all columns from above step
acfMerge  = Reduce(function(x,y) merge.xts(x,y), acfList)

return(acfMerge)
}

#test with lagValue = 2
lag2DF = fn_lag_ACF(lagValue = 2)
```

**Output:**

```
head(lag2DF,15)
#           Convertible.Arbitrage CTA.Global Distressed.Securities Emerging.Markets
#1997-01-31                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-02-28                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-03-31                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-04-30                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-05-31                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-06-30                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-07-31                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-08-31                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-09-30                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-10-31                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-11-30                    NA         NA                    NA               NA
#1997-12-31             0.5560540 -0.3010264            0.02908761        0.3305791
#1998-01-31             0.5055951 -0.4245876            0.04278214        0.1761287
#1998-02-28             0.5195872 -0.4298767            0.01375580        0.1605579
#1998-03-31             0.5070003 -0.4656213           -0.04519778        0.2061610
#           Equity.Market.Neutral
#1997-01-31                    NA
#1997-02-28                    NA
#1997-03-31                    NA
#1997-04-30                    NA
#1997-05-31                    NA
#1997-06-30                    NA
#1997-07-31                    NA
#1997-08-31                    NA
#1997-09-30                    NA
#1997-10-31                    NA
#1997-11-30                    NA
#1997-12-31           -0.11842164
#1998-01-31           -0.05986578
#1998-02-28           -0.09663855
#1998-03-31           -0.09680819
```